# Range variable hides a variable in an enclosing block LINQ

Tags: database, vb.net, linq, variables, range

I have the following 3 queries.   The first works fine but the second two are throwing up an error saying the `range varible Year (or semester, respectively) hides a variable in an enclosing block or a range variable previously defined in the query expression.`  Im not the best at coding so anything I looked up on MSDN just confused me further.  Any help here would be great.

```
Dim compulsoryModule = (From mods In db.Modules
                                Join deg In db.Degrees On mods.Degree_code Equals deg.Degree_code
                                Where deg.Degree_code = degree And mods.Compulsory = True And mods.Level = 1
                                Select mods.Module_code)

        Dim year = (From mods1 In db.Modules
                    Join deg1 In db.Degrees On mods1.Degree_code Equals deg1.Degree_code
                    Where deg1.Degree_code = degree And mods1.Compulsory = True And mods1.Level = 1
                    Select mods1.Year)

        Dim semester = (From mods In db.Modules
                        Join deg In db.Degrees On mods.Degree_code Equals deg.Degree_code
                         Where deg.Degree_code = degree And mods.Compulsory = True And mods.Level = 1
                      Select mods.Semester)
```

The errors are only being thrown on the lines `select mods1.year` and `select mods.semester`  NB in the `year` query the database dims have been changed to have a 1 on them. This was just me trying to fix the problem.  It doesn't change the code if I remove them.

Comment: The error implies there's another variable within scope that is already named Year/Semester. If you remove `Dim` from either variable does the error go away or perhaps become a `Type` error?

Answer (score 6):

I changed the `Dim` year to years and `Dim` semester to semesters.  This has corrected the error

Comment: Glad that worked for you!

Comment: As with everything in the world of coding, it has just opened up a butt load more issues to be figured out haha.  Thanks though

Comment: Yes... It was because the Dim variablename = Linq.SelectedName

Comment: Another solution is to post-fix the variable:
        Dim year = (From mods1 In db.Modules
                    Join deg1 In db.Degrees On mods1.Degree_code Equals deg1.Degree_code
                    Where deg1.Degree_code = degree And mods1.Compulsory = True And mods1.Level = 1
                    Select mods1).FirstOrDefault().Year

        Dim semester = (From mods In db.Modules
                        .......
                      Select mods).FIrstOrDefault().Semester

Comment: With VB, you cannot declare variable names which match anything selected within a Linq query. This only effects VB, and is a little disconcerting that it is not compiled in a separate context like it should.